# Nil and List as case expressions in Scala

Tags: scala

This code compiles:

```
def wtf(arg: Any) = {  
  arg match {  
    case Nil => "Nil was passed to arg"  
    case List() => "List() was passed to arg"  
    case _ =>"otherwise"  
  }  
}
```

But this one does not:

```
def wtf(arg: Any) = {  
  arg match {  
    case List() => "List() was passed to arg"  
    case Nil => "Nil was passed to arg"  
    case _ =>"otherwise"  
  }  
}
```

The line  **case Nil => ...** is marked as unreachable code. Why, in the first case, the line **case List() => ...** is not marked with the same error?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but note that in the first case (the "good" one) the line case List() .... is also unreachable and the compiler does not mark it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual answer requires understanding an unfortunate implementation detail which cost me a lot of time to discover.

1) case List() invokes an extractor, for which no exhaustivity/unreachability checking is possible in the general case because extractors invoke arbitrary functions.  So far so good, we can't be expected to overturn the halting problem.

2) Way back in the more "wild west" days of the compiler, it was determined that pattern matching could be sped up rather a lot (and not lose exhaustivity checking) if "case List()" were just translated to "case Nil" during an early compiler phase so it would avoid the extractor.  This is still the case and although it could be undone, apparently lots of people have been told that "case List() => " is perfectly fine and we don't want to pessimize all their code all of a sudden.  So I just have to figure out a road out.

You can see empirically that List is privileged by trying it with some other class.  No unreachability errors.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq
val Empty: IndexedSeq[Nothing] = IndexedSeq()
def wtf1(arg: Any) = {  
  arg match {  
    case Empty => "Nil was passed to arg"  
    case IndexedSeq() => "IndexedSeq() was passed to arg"  
    case _ =>"otherwise"  
  }  
}

def wtf2(arg: Any) = {  
  arg match {  
    case IndexedSeq() => "IndexedSeq() was passed to arg"  
    case Empty => "Nil was passed to arg"  
    case _ =>"otherwise"  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The discrepancy is particularly weird since the code for the `Nil` case in the second version is definitely *not* unreachable, as we can see if we hide things from the compiler a bit:

```
def wtf(arg: Any) = {
  arg match {
    case List() => "List() was passed to arg"  
    case x => x match {
      case Nil => "Nil was passed to arg"
      case _ =>"otherwise"
    }
  }
}
```

Now `wtf(Vector())` will return `"Nil was passed to arg"`. This may also seem counterintuitive, but it's because literal patterns match values that are equal in terms of `==`, and `Vector() == Nil`, but `Vector()` doesn't match the extractor pattern `List()`.

More concisely:

```
scala> (Vector(): Seq[_]) match { case List() => true; case Nil => false }
<console>:8: error: unreachable code

scala> (Vector(): Seq[_]) match { case List() => true; case x => x match { case Nil => false } }
res0: Boolean = false
```

So the compiler's response is completely reversed: in the "good" version the second case is unreachable, and in the "bad" version the second case is perfectly fine. I've [reported this as a bug (SI-5029)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5029).

Comment: You're not comparing like with like in your last example, the following also produces false case x if x == scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer() => false

Comment: @Matthew, if the compiler allowed us (correctly, I think) to write `case Nil => false`, then `Nil` would be a literal pattern and would match using `==`. In your example `ListBuffer()` is an extractor pattern, which doesn't (necessarily) use `==`. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Comment: My comment wasn't very clear—I just mean that `case x if x == ListBuffer()` isn't equivalent to `case ListBuffer()`, while `case x if x == Nil` is equivalent to `case Nil`.

Comment: My point is that the case x if == is a guard clause, not an extractor pattern. When you use case directly, it's doing an extra check that the classes are compatible. According to your logic the two are equivalent, but try (Vector(): Any) match { case scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer() => "listBuffer"} as opposed to  (Vector(): Any) match { case x if x == new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer() => "listBuffer" }

Comment: @Matthew, I've changed that second example to avoid obscuring the point, but I'm pretty sure it's still the case that `case Nil` matches exactly the same input as `case x if x == Nil`, since `Nil` is a literal pattern, not an extractor pattern (like `ListBuffer()`, for example, where the two are different, as you point out).

Answer (score 5):

`Nil` is an object extending `List[Nothing]`.  Being more specific than `List()`, it isn't reached if it appears after `List()` in the case expression.

While I think the above is more or less true, it's likely not the whole story.

There are hints in the article [Matching Objects with Patterns](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~emir/written/MatchingObjectsWithPatterns-TR.pdf), though I don't see a definitive answer there.

I suspect that detection of unreachability is simply more completely implemented for named constants and literals than for constructor patterns, and that `List()` is being interpreted as a constructor pattern (even though it's a trivial one), while `Nil` is a named constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but note that in the first case (the "good" one) the line case List() .... is also unreachable and the compiler does not mark it. def(List()) returns "Nil was passed to arg"

Comment: @Don, maybe you can explain in your answer why there are some empty lists that are not `Nil`?

Comment: @Dan, actually I don't think there are empty lists that aren't Nil.

Comment: @Don, oh, I see. So `Nil` is just a more specific case because of how it's declared in the standard Scala library.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find anything in the language specification with respect to unreachable match clauses. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

So I assume that unreachable compilation errors are on a best effort basis, which may explain why the first case does not complain.

`scala -Xprint:typer` suggests that `Nil` is a *literal pattern* using `immutable.this.Nil.==` to check for a match, while `List()` is an *extractor pattern*. Looking at the implementation of the extractor in it seems to be doing something like [this](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/generic/GenSeqFactory.scala#L25):

```
def unapplySeq[A](x: CC[A]): Some[CC[A]] = Some(x)
```

So I got curious and rolled out an alternate implementation:

```
object ListAlt {
  def unapplySeq[A](l: List[A]): Some[List[A]] = Some(l)
}
```

It matches like `List()`:

```
scala> Nil match { case ListAlt() => 1 }
res0: Int = 1
```

But if I implement your function with it, it compiles fine (except for unchecked warning):

```
def f(a: Any) = a match { case ListAlt() => 1 case Nil => 2 case _ => 0 }

scala> f(List())
res2: Int = 1

scala> f(Nil)
res3: Int = 1

scala> f(4)
res4: Int = 0
```

So I am wondering if the pattern matcher implementation has some special casing for `Nil` and `List()`. May be it treats List() as a literal...

Comment: "May be it treats List() as a literal..." Very insightful, that's essentially exactly what it does.

Comment: (Assuming the set of things which are essentially exact is not empty.)

Comment: @extempore, cool, I did try to look at ParallelMatching.scala and other files under scala/tools/nsc/matching but I gave up after 20 minutes or so.