# What is the idiomatic way to pattern match sequence comprehensions?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

```
val x = for(i <- 1 to 3) yield i
x match {
    case 1 :: rest => ... // compile error
}
```

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found :
>   collection.immutable.::[B] required:
>   scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]

This is the same problem as [MatchError when match receives an IndexedSeq but not a LinearSeq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199171/matcherror-when-match-receives-an-indexedseq-but-not-a-linearseq).

The question is, how to do it right? Adding `.toList` everywhere doesn't seem right. And creating an own extractor which handles every `Seq` (as described in the answer of the other question) would lead to a mess if everybody would do it...

I guess the question is, why can't I influence what the return type of sequence comprehensions is, or: why isn't such a generalized `Seq` extractor part of the standard library?

Comment: This generalized extractor is available in 2.10: `val a +: b = 0 until 10` works like `val a :: b = (0 until 10).toList` does in 2.9.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting! Although I'm not sure if it will also create a bit of mess having two extractors for lists. Is this extractor then supposed to replace ::? After all, it can do the same thing and is more generic.

Comment: @TravisBrown that's good to know. Is there an equivalent of List's `Nil` as well?

Comment: @Luigi: I don't think so—possibly because the `Seq(a, b, c)` syntax would be clearer in most situations where you want to match on `Nil`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Good point. To check for the empty sequence, it would just be `Seq()`. Although according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7602498/770361, `case List() => ` was a lot slower than `case Nil => ` before a dubious hack was put in to convert `List()` to `Nil`. So I hope that some way is found to ensure good performance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, you can pattern-match any sequence:

```
case Seq(a, b, rest @ _ *) =>
```

For example:

```
scala> def mtch(s: Seq[Int]) = s match { 
  |      case Seq(a, b, rest @ _ *) => println("Found " + a + " and " + b)
  |      case _ => println("Bah") 
  |    }
mtch: (s: Seq[Int])Unit
```

Then this will match any sequence with more than (or equal to) 2 elements

```
scala> mtch(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
Found 1 and 2

scala> mtch(Seq(1, 2, 3))
Found 1 and 2

scala> mtch(Vector(1, 2))
Found 1 and 2

scala> mtch(Vector(1))
Bah
```

Comment: I get scala.MatchError: Vector(1, 2, 3) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Vector) with that. Isn't it possible to only match case classes like that?

Comment: It's possible to match anything with an extractor - in this case, anything with an `unapplySeq` method.

Comment: Somewhere I read that instead of using `List` in method signatures it's better to use `Seq` if that also describes the problem. So if I have Seq everywhere, should I then always use Seq(..) pattern matching as the idiomatic way? Because with Seq I probably shouldn't match on List or :: anyway. Or wait for 2.10 and use +: everywhere?

Comment: Well, 2.10 is several months away. I would usually use `List` myself, unless I am converting some huge data structure, in which case pattern-matching might not be the best bet anyway. If you are just testing for emptiness, you can always use `headOption`

Comment: What I actually do now is matching `Seq()` for empty seqs, `Seq(a,b)` for fixed numbers of elements and `a +: rest` for head tail matching. I actually copied the relevant [extractors](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala/commit/b3efb3d493605d1c7e106e5f0a697b52ebb3d97c) into my project and created package objects with `+:` and `:+` for each package so that I don't have to import anything and can just delete those once 2.10 comes out.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution for Vector in REPL:

```
Vector() match {
    case a +: as => "head + tail"
    case _       => "empty"  
}
 res0: String = "empty"

Vector(1,2) match {
  case a +: as => s"$a + $as"
  case _      => "empty"  }
res1: String = 1 + Vector(2)
```