# Return tail if list is not empty or return empty list

Tags: scala

From the list of emails I have to get 2 values:

- option of the head of the list
- list of the rest of them

What is the idiomatic way to code this in scala? So far I have:

```
val primaryEmail = emails.headOption
val conf = Map[String, Any](
  "email" -> primaryEmail,
  "additionalEmails" -> 
     primaryEmail.map(_ => emails.tail).getOrElse(List())
)
```

EDIT: As to why there is `Any`: We use GSON for json serialization, and internally convert all collections to java collections and pass them to [jsonSerializationContext.serialize](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializationContext.html#serialize%28java.lang.Object%29), which have java.lang.Object as an argument, so `Any` suits us just fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would probably just `drop` the first element (if you're sure that the first element always is the primary email). Like so:

```
val conf = Map[String, Any](
  "email" -> emails.headOption,
  "additionalEmails" -> emails.drop(1)
)
```

This doesn't give an exception if the primary email is not in the list (the list is empty).

Answer (score 8):

Learn you a **scalaz**. All this is available in one call:

```
val (primary, rest) =  list <^> (nel => some(nel.head) -> nel.tail)
val conf = Map("email" -> primary, "additionalEmails" -> rest)
```

Demonstration:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

If non-empty

```
scala> val (primary, rest) =  list <^> (nel => some(nel.head) -> nel.tail)
primary: Option[Int] = Some(1)
rest: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

if empty:

```
scala> val list = List.empty[Int]
list: List[Int] = List()

scala> val (primary, rest) =  list <^> (nel => some(nel.head) -> nel.tail)
primary: Option[Int] = None
rest: List[Int] = List()
```

---

### How does this work?

The `<^>` call says: *if this list is empty, return the **zero** for the type as defined by the return type function to the right. If the list is non-empty, apply the function to it*

The value `nel` is a `NonEmptyList`, which I can safely call `head` and `tail` on without fearing that they will throw an exception. My function returns a `(Option[A], List[A])`

Of course, the *zero* for this is just `(None, Nil)` for any `A`

Comment: Is this still a thing? Operator doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

For sequences you can pattern match on them to get the head and the rest as

```
val lst1 = Seq("primary", "secondary", "other");
// ...
lst1 match {
  case Seq(primary, rest @ _*)  => println(primary + "/" + rest);
  case _                        => println("Error: list empty.");
}
```

If you use Scala's `List`s, it's even nicer:

```
val lst2 = List("primary", "secondary", "other");
// ...
lst2 match {
  case primary :: rest  => println(primary + "/" + rest);
  case Nil              => println("Error: list empty.");
}
```

See also [What is the idiomatic way to pattern match sequence comprehensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11503033/1333025) and [Scala pattern matching on sequences other than Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6807540/1333025).

---

Just as Reuben, I'd strongy discourage you from using `Map[String,Any]` or similar constructions. You're throwing away everything Scala's type system gives you. It's easy to get errors that are very hard-to-trace. Perhaps ask it as another question - describe why you use `Map[String,Any]` now and ask how it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Map[String,Any] ?  You might as well just write PHP ... ;-)

Here's another way:

```
scala> def build( emails:Seq[String] ):Map[String,Any] =
 emails.headOption.map(
         (primary) => Map( "primary" -> Some(primary), "other" -> emails.tail )
   ).getOrElse( Map( "primary" -> None, "other" -> Nil ) )
build: (emails: Seq[String])Map[String,Any]

scala> build(Nil)
res2: Map[String,Any] = Map(primary -> None, other -> List())

scala> build( List("fred"))
res3: Map[String,Any] = Map(primary -> Some(fred), other -> List())
```

Really - I don't like the whole approach - I'd do something like this:

```
case class EmailTo( primary:String, other:Seq[String] );

object EmailTo {
    def apply( addrs:Seq[String] ):Option[EmailTo] = 
         addrs.headOption.map( (primary) => EmailTo( primary, addrs.tail ) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
(("email", "additionalEmail") zip emails.splitAt(1)).toMap
```

This leaves the first email in a `List` not an `Option`, but a `Map[String, Product]` isn't going to do you much good anyway, is it?