# Non-exhaustive Pattern Match Warning with Tuple

Tags: scala

Given the following `sealed trait`:

```
scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Boy extends Parent
defined object Boy

scala> case object Girl extends Parent
defined object Girl
```

And given `xs`:

```
scala> val xs: (Parent, (Seq[Int], Seq[Int])) = (Boy, (Nil, Nil))
xs: (Parent, (Seq[Int], Seq[Int])) = (Boy,(List(),List()))

scala> xs match { 
     |   case (Boy, (Nil, Nil))     => 1
     |   case (Boy, (ys, a :: as))  => 2
     |   case (Boy, (ys, Nil))      => 3
     |   case (Girl, (Nil, Nil))    => 4
     |   case (Girl, (a :: as, ys)) => 5
     |   case (Girl, (Nil, ys))     => 6
     | }
<console>:15: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: (Boy, _), (Girl, _)
       xs match {
       ^
res1: Int = 1
```

I don't understand this inexhaustive match warning. What do `(Boy, _)` and `(Girl, _)` mean?

I'm not sure how the `(Seq[Int], Seq[Int])` could have any other match than what I have on the right-hand side.

Comment: Short answer: `::` is the extractor for `List`s. You need `Seq` to extract `Seq`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it seems Scala has trouble with the `unapply` (or is it `apply`) for Seq which is the magic that makes the pattern matching possible. Apparently the `cons` in your matches is an issue with `Seq`. If you changes your xs to use `List`, it would work:

```
val xs: (Parent, (List[Int], List[Int])) = (Boy, (Nil, Nil))
```

EDIT:

It may be that you can use `Seq` but just have to pattern match on the construction slightly differently, like this:

```
  xs match {
    case (Boy, (Nil, Nil)) => 1
    case (Boy, (_, Seq(x, _))) => 2
    case (Boy, (_, Nil)) => 3
    case (Girl, (Nil, Nil)) => 4
    case (Girl, (Seq(x, _), _)) => 5
    case (Girl, (Nil, _)) => 6
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't it make sense? Not all nonempty `Seq`s are instances of `::`.

Comment: I liked this answer too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503033/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-pattern-match-sequence-comprehensions